# Get null for google maps while initializing Aeris Map View

Tags: java, android, google-maps, weather-api

I am following the tutorial to create a simple aeris map.

*Error Details:*

```
12-04 11:55:51.216 22405-22405/usc.forecast.weather E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: usc.forecast.weather, PID: 22405
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{usc.forecast.weather/usc.forecast.weather.MapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.hamweather.aeris.maps.AerisMapView.init(AerisMapView.java:219)
   at usc.forecast.weather.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:32)**
   at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

***mapView.init(savedInstanceState, AerisMapType.GOOGLE);***

And inside init method of AerisMapView.java(third party, [aeris weather](http://www.aerisweather.com/support/docs/toolkits/aeris-android-sdk/getting-started/weather-maps/))

```
public void init(Bundle savedInstanceState, AerisMapView.AerisMapType type) {
        this.type = type;
        switch(null.$SwitchMap$com$hamweather$aeris$maps$AerisMapView$AerisMapType[type.ordinal()]) {
        case 1:
            this.mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getContext());
            this.googleMap = this.mapView.getMap(); <-------
            this.googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
            this.googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
            this.googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
            this.markerAdapter = new AerisGoogleInfoAdapter();
            this.googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
            this.googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(this.markerAdapter);
        default:
        }
    }
```

*My code:*

MapFragment.java

```
public class MapFragment extends MapViewFragment implements  OnAerisMapLongClickListener, AerisCallback {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AerisEngine.initWithKeys(this.getString(R.string.aeris_client_id), this.getString(R.string.aeris_client_secret), "usc.forecast.weather");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_interactive_maps, container, false);
        mapView = (AerisMapView) view.findViewById(R.id.aerisfragment_map);
        mapView.init(savedInstanceState, AerisMapType.GOOGLE);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        String lat = bundle.getString("lat");
        String lng = bundle.getString("lng");

        Location location = new Location("");
        location.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(lat));
        location.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(lng));

        mapView.moveToLocation(location);
        mapView.addLayer(AerisTile.RADSAT);

        mapView.setOnAerisMapLongClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(double lat, double longitude) {
        // code to handle map long press. i.e. Fetch current conditions?
        // see demo app MapFragment.java
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(EndpointType type, AerisResponse response) {

    }}
```

MapActivity.java

```
public class MapActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String lat = intent.getStringExtra("lat");
    String lng = intent.getStringExtra("lng");


    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("lat", lat);
    bundle.putString("lng", lng);

    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}}
```

activity_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_interactive_maps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.hamweather.aeris.maps.AerisMapView
        android:id="@+id/aerisfragment_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </com.hamweather.aeris.maps.AerisMapView>
</LinearLayout>
```

build.gradle(project)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "usc.forecast.weather"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.hamweather:aeris-maps-library:1.1.1@aar'}
```

Comment: you need to use onMapReadyCallback instead of mapView.getMap() https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback

Comment: @AngelKoh... AriesMapView is part of the third party library and not under my control. I added it here to show where it is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this was happening was that that my Google Play Services on my phone is outdated. The newest version of Android Studio is using latest API SDK to compile the app and hence google maps was returning null.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include these `MapView` calls in these lifecycle events.

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
```

EDIT: For MapFragment to initialize and start using it you generally need to do this:

```
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Then when it loads this override is called and you can use it then (this may be why it's null as you're trying to use it too early).

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

}
```

Also make sure you include this implement statement in your `Fragment` or `Activity`:

```
implements OnMapReadyCallback
```

`MapFragment` doesn't need to be tied into the lifecycler like a `MapView` does (above) as it is a `Fragment` and handles it on it's own.

Comment: I do not interact with google's mapView directly. The third party AerisMapView has GoogleMap in its class and initializes google maps as part of the AerisMapView initialization.

Comment: I'd recommend not using it if you can. It seems outdated, sorry if this doesn't help.

If you need help setting up Google Maps without Aeries I'll gladly help.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this issue linking to the (current)  com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4 version of the maps SDK, and I believe the issue also occurs with 9.2.1.

Aeris has recognized the issue and suggests that you stick with com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0 until they bring out and SDK update (planned for Q4, 2016).